# i am trying to open a tab using controller function but it show me error

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

[ my controller code is here  [i was try to load my contact file that i have been saved in pages file but t show me the error] [Error :: Unable to load the requested file: pages.php]

```
public function contact(){
        $page_data['page_title']    = 'contact';
        $page_data['page_name']     = 'contact';

        $this->load->view('pages', $page_data);
    }
```

[i was try to load my contact file that i have been saved in pages file]

Comment: check the spelling, and casing ( capitalization ) of the file.  On Linux, for example, `pages.php` is not the same as `Pages.php` on windows it is, but not on Linux.

Comment: i check my file and code spellings but both are same, i try to change code public function contact(){
  $page_data['page_title']    = 'Contact';
  $page_data['page_name']     = 'contact';

  $this->load->view('/pageheader');
  $this->load->view('web_navigation');
  $this->load->view('slider');
  $this->load->view('pages/', $page_data);
  $this->load->view('footer');
 }

Comment: $this->load->view('pageheader');
  $this->load->view('web_navigation');
  $this->load->view('slider');
  $this->load->view('pages/contact');
  $this->load->view('footer');  
[this is solution that i have been found, but i think this is not  better way . is it? what are say @ArtisticPhoenix  about this?]